# IndexedContainer not found in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

We are migrating from Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8 and we heavily are using `IndexedContainer`. This class is not found in this version. Is there actually any quick fix or do we have to do some major refactoring? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The big change between Vaadin 7 and 8 is the new type-safe data API. Instead of container/item/property, you have now data providers and typed components. You can give items to components directly e.g. `grid.setItems(myList)` and configure with `grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");`. Check out more examples in the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers.html#datamodel.providers

If the migration work is big, then you can make use of the compatibility package. It is meant for migrating, and it has the V7 APIs, including IndexedContainer. You can then move one screen at a time to V8 model. Read more about it here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html